# How to get type information about running action server?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am new to ROS.
I have finished tutorials and I understand how to create simple action server & client.

Next, I would like to know how to get type information about running action server.
For example, if you want to send a new goal with an action client, you will write as follows.

> client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
> goal = MoveBaseGoal()
> ...Set goal parameter
> client.send_goal(goal)

To write this code, users have to know that "move_base" requires MoveBaseAction and MoveBaseGoal.
Of course, I can learn the dependency from Wiki page. But, are there any other smart way to get these dependency information from running action server?

Thanks a lot for your attention!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247840/how-to-get-type-information-about-running-action-server?/) by [vivitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28504/vivitter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Currently, as can be read in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/222748/list-action-servers/) question, there is no simple way to list the action servers. Running `rostopic list |  grep feedback` as suggested, you can see the ones that are running. (every action server broadcasts a goal, results, feedback, status and cancel topic)

When the move group is running, `rostopic list | grep feedback` will return at least:

```
/move_group/feedback
/pickup/feedback
/place/feedback
```

Then you can use `rostopic info` to find the type of these topics. for instance: `rostopic info /move_group/feedback` returns:

```
Type: moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionFeedback
```

As a last step you can run `rosmsg show moveit_msgs/MoveGroupAction` to get the full message definition (`rosmsg show moveit_msgs/MoveGroupActionFeedback` will only show the feedback part). As it is the completely expanded tree of the message it is quite long and I won't post it here, but you get the idea.

All in all, I find looking at the message definition in the [message definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/action/MoveGroup.html) easier, but this will also work.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vivitter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28504/vivitter/) on 2016-11-11**:
Hi, rbbg.
Thank you very much for your help!
I am very sorry for the duplicate question.

I think such a demand is very common.
I hope more simple API will be released in the future. I will consider how to implement it.